# Convert lots of if's to something smaller

Tags: c#

I need to check a char array and convert every char to a random number value into a int array;

I have managed to do this but with a lot of code.
Is there anyway I can write less code?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            if (oddF[i] == '0')
            {
                oddFlValue[i] = 1;
                continue;
            }
            else if (oddF[i] == '1')
            {
                oddFValue[i] = 0;
                continue;
            }
            else if (oddFiscal[i] == '8')
            {
                oddFiscalValue[i] = 19;
                continue;
            }
            else if (oddF[i] == '9')
            {
                oddFValue[i] = 21;
                continue;
            }
            else if ((oddF[i] == 'a') || (oddF[i] == 'A'))
            {
                oddFValue[i] = 1;
                continue;
            }
            else if ((oddF[i] == 'b') || (oddF[i] == 'B'))
            {
                oddFValue[i] = 0;
                continue;
            }
```

This is just a sample as I need to check for every number and letter type.
Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use a switch statement? Additionally the `continue` is unnecessary as it will automatically go to the next iteration if there is nothing more for it to do.

Comment: Is `oddFiscal` a typo?

Comment: You say you need to store random integer values but I see no random here.

Comment: `switch (Char.ToLower(oddF[i])) { ... }`

Comment: @LarsTech it seems that I've forgot it there :/

Comment: @MatiasCicero by random i mean that the number don't have a pattern, they just exist and I can't change them

Comment: @EliSadoff removed continue; thanks!

Comment: To add to the question by @LarsTech: are `oddFlValue` and `oddFiscalValue` also typos?  I'm almost certain they are (and so should be fixed in the question), but if not those differences complicate things a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this would be to use a `Dictionary<char, int>`, and get its value. Something like this:

```
Dictionary<char, int> MyCombinations = new Dictionary<char, int>{
    {'0', 1},
    {'5', 15},
    /*etc etc etc*/
};
```

And then use it like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    oddFValue[i] = MyCombinations[oddFiscal[i]];
}
```

Comment: I would only change the way you instantiate dictionary to be in a form {{a,b},{c,d}} but it's the simplest solution

Comment: @cFrozenDeath This dictionary thing seems to be a nice solution!

Comment: @abelenky You seem like a nice person

Comment: I edited your answer to correct syntax error, and remove unnecessary parts.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        char[] oddF           = new char[8]{'0','1','8','A','b','9','a','B'};
         int[] oddFValue      = new int[8];

        Dictionary<char, int> table = new Dictionary<char, int>(){
            { '0', 1  },
            { '1', 0  },
            { '8', 19 },
            { '9', 21 },
            { 'a', 1  },
            { 'A', 1  },
            { 'b', 0  },
            { 'B', 0  }
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            oddFValue[i] = table[oddF[i]]; // Lookup which function should be called, and call it.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't really get the point of creating the delegate and all that stuff when the OP is just making a static assignment. Seems like too much work for no actual gain

Comment: I don't really like this idea. I agree with @cFrozenDeath it's too complicated. Why not to create a simple dictionary with  plain mappings? Btw procedure should be outside the loop

Comment: The question was how can I write less code.  I think this reduces the code a bit. (and I'm working on making a shorter version)

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```
public int? ConvertCharToInt(char c)
{
    switch (c)
    {
        case '0': return 1;
        case '1': return 0;
        case '8': return 19;
        case '9': return 21;
        case 'a':
        case 'A': return 1;
        case 'b':
        case 'B': return 0;
        // ...
        default: return null;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    int? number = ConvertCharToInt(oddF[i]);
    if (number.HasValue)
         oddFValue[i] = number.Value;
    else
         // Character cannot be converted to int value
}
```

Comment: The original post also changed which array ***receives*** the assignment.  Sometimes it is `oddFlValue`, sometimes `oddFiscalValue`, sometimes `oddFValue`.  Your solution does not capture that part ***at all***.

Comment: @abelenky OP stated that it was a typo. It is always the same array. See accepted answer and comments. Why the downvotes?